# Force customer to log in when visiting a specific category Magento 2

Tags: magento2, catalog, login

I have found that https://github.com/bitExpert/magento2-force-login and I just install it but I don't know how to use it: how to force not logged in the customer to login or create an account before being redirected to /my category ??!!! I just find the whitelist and it seems that no justification for this list the force to log in is omitted but for all URL in my store. please help me I am really new in Magento 2 and this is my first project. 
thanks  in advance

Comment: What issue are you facing in this it is redirecting you to login page when entering into website.

Comment: when i tried this it does not redirect me to login page, as if  i did'nt installed

Comment: how did you installed using composer i just installed it using composer and enable the module in admin after setup:upgrade it is working fine.

Comment: i enabled the module but the problem is that when i added !/my category path  and removed all other url in white list , i excepct to be redirected to login page when accessing to /my category but no result

Comment: can you please more explain about category what you are exactly doing.i change the path of category at my end and checked still working.

Comment: i have a category named "just for membre" (contains products) so when i click on top menu on Just for member  and i am not logged in or i don't have account  so i have to sihn in before access to the content of this category

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82357/discussion-between-charul-tyagi-and-developper-magento).